# Clojure function to save a smnaller value of the number returned by a query

Tags: clojure

I am running a query that returns a single number, for example say 35.

I want to store this number in clojure,

then get 20% of that value and save that number also.

I want to then be able to pass this 20% value into queries to LIMIT by the 20% number.

The reason for this being a pareto analysis based query.

Can anyone help with this?

query(str "SELECT COUNT(Application) AS NUMBER FROM AppTable")

numb(map #(get % "number") query)

then need to divide num by 5, save a new number with this value and use it to pass to queries.

Comment: Sample code is better to understand the problem more.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what you mean by the word "then". Is this all part of the same operation? If so, use the following:

```
(let [query-result (my-query ...)
      one-fifth (double (* 0.2 query-result))]
  (my-other-queries one-fifth ...))
```

If you want to perform the final queries independently from the first query, you probably have to use some kind of mutable state, e.g. an `atom`:

```
(def query-result (atom nil))
...
(reset! query-result (my-query ...))
...
(my-other-queries (double (* 0.2 @query-result)) ...)
```

Note that you can always generate the 20% value from the original query result. Also, better check if `query-result` really contains a value before running `my-other-queries`.

Comment: will storing it as a double allow it to be passed to a query? What i mean is if the original query returns 36 and you multiply it by 0.2 this will be 7.2, and obviously you cant LIMIt results to 7.2 in an SQL query

Comment: Well, you can convert it to long, too. You might want to round it manually, though, if you want to achieve a specific behaviour.